# getting permission denied when using ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to setup ssh access using keys - I have added my public key to the .ssh directory on the server.  I restarted the ssh service on the server as well.  When I logon from my local computer to the server, I get a denied message (copied below - using the v flag).  I replaced the username and ip address from the question.  Any idea what I might have done wrong?

```
ssh -v user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA dd:e7:a3:31:60:21:c5:90:24:b5:11:65:43:d8:cd:a0
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I copied over the id_rsa private key file to id_rsa - now its at least finding the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to copy the id_rsa file (private key) that I had created to the id_dsa file that the ssh process was looking for (previously not created).  Using the ssh -v command helped me figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

- ensure the permissions of the .ssh directory and authorized_keys are right as in 0700 for .ssh and 0600 for ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. If not, fix this first.
- ensure key authentication is enabled on your server but this should be ok by default, check your sshd_config to confirm.
- check your log files on your server, on RedHat / Fedora and most linux distros you can find them in /var/log/secure
- You don't need to restart the sshd daemon to let him know your newly added keys.

**Preferably use ssh-copy-id to copy your keys to the server.**

See here, it's Ubuntu specific but as we're talking about OpenSSH it works anyway:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: thank you Fredi - I did those steps previously (permissions etc.).  Much appreciated